# React Router get name of matched component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router 0.13.3 for server side rendering and I'd like to get name of matched component inside run callback. I need to add condition the will be true just for a certain route, so I tried something like this:

```js
app.serve(function (req, res) {
  Router.run(routes, req.path, function (Root, state) {
    if(Root.displayName === 'myComponent'){
      //do something specific
    } else{
      var html = React.renderToString(<Root/>);
      res.send(html);
    }
    });
  });
});
```

But this one always returns a string 'Router'.

If this is not possible to do in 0.13.3, is there a way to do it in 1.0.0?

Comment: I tried to use state.matches as defined here http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Router.run, but is always undefined.

Comment: which part returns the string?

Comment: Don't understand, Rei Dien.

Comment: Nothing returns correct string at the moment, this is not a working code.